# How to use Soft Keys in Blackberry Application?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lcdui, midp-2.0

My application in J2ME, I have just changed Emulator Platform to Blackberry JDE 6.0.0 and Device 9800.

After applying above configuration in Netbeans I got MyApp.cod file. I have installed it on my device Blackberry but problem is I used mostly Canvas and I used softkeys for options. Trackball working with Left, UP, Down & Right it's fine. But my soft keys which I provided on canvas it's not working? What I have to make changes in my canvas to use soft keys of blackberry?

Here is code ::

```
     protected void keyPressed(int keyCode) {
        action = getGameAction(keyCode);
        if(keyCode == -7)
        {
            // for go to back
            Display.getDisplay(midlet).setCurrent(midlet.aolMenuCanvas);
        }
        else if(keyCode == -6)
        {
            try {
               //midlet.DownloadPhoto((imageName[index_send]),++index_send);
                 midlet.DownloadPhoto(imgName[index]);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: @Sahjid What do you mean by saying "soft keys provided on canvas"?

Comment: I have two images on both side of Canvas in Left Bottom & Right Bottom, if user clicks left soft key i am making some changes in canvas. I used keycode for that purpose.

Comment: @Sahjid Please post the relevant code snippet.

Comment: instead of LSK and RSK use the KEY_STAR and KEY_POUND (* and # )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736305/j2me-soft-key-wrapper/1739325#1739325) and it's accepted answer.In the other hand
you can add 2 commands with the same priority to the canvas and handle your changes in commandAction(Command cmnd, Displayable dsplbl)method.If you want that your command's labels be hidden,set canvas full screen mode to true.