# How to get the keycode for different mobiles using j2me

Tags: netbeans, java-me, using, platform

I am developing application for Nokia using Netbeans platform.

Now I am in idea to make this application to work on any java enabled mobile. So for that I have to get the platform of the devices, how can I get it(specifically for micromax, blackberry) mobiles? Also the left and right softkey code.

Answer (score 1):

I found one answer which is given [this link](http://www.iteye.com/topic/179073).
the KeyCodeAdapter class provided by above link is like below

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas;

/**
 * Class redefines codes of mobile phone to our constant values.
 * Class can give to developers following information:
 * <ul>
 * <li/><i>defined platform name</i><br>
 * In case if device vendor not defined we'll recieve <code>PLATFORM_NOT_DEFINED</code> like platform name.
 * Same in this case keyCodes will be setted like for Nokia and SE. It's done for work on emulators,
 * because on some of them it's impossible to define platform name.
 * <li/><i>adopted to our constants key code value</i>
 * <li/><i>for test returns defined real code of left softkey</i>
 * </ul>
 */
public final class KeyCodeAdapter {

    /**
     * instance on this class
     */
    private static final KeyCodeAdapter instance = new KeyCodeAdapter();
    /**
     * canvas used for definig codes
     */
    private final Canvas adaptorCanvas;
    /**
     * constants for platforms  names
     */
    public static final String PLATFORM_MOTOROLA = "motorola";
    public static final String PLATFORM_NOKIA = "nokia";
    public static final String PLATFORM_SONY_ERICSSON = "SE";
    public static final String PLATFORM_SIEMENS = "siemens";
    public static final String PLATFORM_SAMSUNG = "samsung";
    public static final String PLATFORM_LG = "LG";
    public static final String PLATFORM_NOT_DEFINED = "NA";
    /**
     * constants for keycodes
     */
    public static final int SOFT_KEY_LEFT = -201;
    public static final int SOFT_KEY_RIGHT = -202;
    public static final int SOFT_KEY_MIDDLE_INTERNET = -203;
    /**
     * this key is present on Nokia s60
     */
    public static final int PENCIL_KEY = -207;
    public static final int DELETE_KEY = -204;
    public static final int BACK_KEY = -205;
    //    public static final int SEND_KEY = -206; //constant will be used in future for green key start dialling
    public static final int KEY_1 = 201;
    public static final int KEY_2 = 202;
    public static final int KEY_3 = 203;
    public static final int KEY_4 = 204;
    public static final int KEY_5 = 205;
    public static final int KEY_6 = 206;
    public static final int KEY_7 = 207;
    public static final int KEY_8 = 208;
    public static final int KEY_9 = 209;
    public static final int KEY_0 = 200;
    public static final int KEY__POUND = 211;
    public static final int KEY__STAR = 212;
    /**
     * KEYS on JOISTICK
     */
    public static final int UP_KEY = 221;
    public static final int DOWN_KEY = 222;
    public static final int LEFT_KEY = 223;
    public static final int RIGHT_KEY = 224;
    public static final int CENTER_KEY = 225;

    public static final int NOT_DEFINED_KEY = 254;

    /**
     * current platform name
     */
    private final String PLATFORM_NAME;
    /**
     * current platform codeofSoftkey
     */
    private final int SOFTKEY_LEFT;
    private final int SOFTKEY_RIGHT;
    private final int SOFTKEY_MIDDLE_INTERNET;
    private final int SOFTKEY_DELETE;
    private final int SOFTKEY_BACK;

    /**
     * standart values for softkeys of different platforms
     * used only in predefining
     */
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_LEFT_SE = -6;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_SE = -7;
    private static final int DELETE_KEY_SE = -8;
    private static final int INTERNET_KEY_SE = -10;
    private static final int BACK_KEY_SE = -11;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_LEFT_SAMSUNG = -6;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_SAMSUNG = -7;
    private static final int DELETE_KEY_SAMSUNG = -8;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_LEFT_SIEMENS = -1;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_SIEMENS = -4;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_LEFT_NOKIA = -6;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_NOKIA = -7;
    private static final int DELETE_KEY_NOKIA = -8;
    private static final int PENCIL_KEY_NOKIA = -50;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA = -21;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_MOTOROLA = -22;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA2 = -20;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA1 = 21;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_MOTOROLA1 = 22;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_MIDLE_MOTOROLA = -23;
    private static final int SOFT_KEY_MIDLE_NOKIA = -5;

    private static final String SOFT_WORD = "SOFT";

    /**
     * constructor.
     * here is predefining of spesial keys and platform made
     */
    private KeyCodeAdapter() {
        adaptorCanvas = MainCanvas.getInstance();
        PLATFORM_NAME = getPlatform();
        SOFTKEY_LEFT = getLeftSoftkeyCode();
        SOFTKEY_RIGHT = getRightSoftkeyCode();
        SOFTKEY_MIDDLE_INTERNET = getMidleORInternetSoftkeyCode();
        SOFTKEY_DELETE = getDeleteKeyCode();
        SOFTKEY_BACK = getBackKeyCode();
    }

    /**
     * return platform keycode of left softkey
     * if it's defined
     * default value -6
     *
     * @return SOFTKEY_LEFT
     */
    public int getPlatformSoftkeyLeftCode() {
        return SOFTKEY_LEFT;
    }

    /**
     * Returns mobile phone platform
     *
     * @return name mobile phone platform
     */
    private String getPlatform() {
        // detecting NOKIA or SonyEricsson
        try {
            final String currentPlatform = System.getProperty("microedition.platform");
            if (currentPlatform.indexOf("Nokia") != -1) {
                return PLATFORM_NOKIA;
            } else if (currentPlatform.indexOf("SonyEricsson") != -1) {
                return PLATFORM_SONY_ERICSSON;
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
        }
        // detecting SAMSUNG
        try {
            Class.forName("com.samsung.util.Vibration");
            return PLATFORM_SAMSUNG;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
        }
        // detecting MOTOROLA
        try {
            Class.forName("com.motorola.multimedia.Vibrator");
            return PLATFORM_MOTOROLA;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.motorola.graphics.j3d.Effect3D");
                return PLATFORM_MOTOROLA;
            } catch (Throwable ex2) {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.motorola.multimedia.Lighting");
                    return PLATFORM_MOTOROLA;
                } catch (Throwable ex3) {
                    try {
                        Class.forName("com.motorola.multimedia.FunLight");
                        return PLATFORM_MOTOROLA;
                    } catch (Throwable ex4) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            if (adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA).toUpperCase().indexOf(SOFT_WORD) > -1) {
                return PLATFORM_MOTOROLA;
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            try {
                if (adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA1).toUpperCase().indexOf(SOFT_WORD) > -1) {
                    return PLATFORM_MOTOROLA;
                }
            } catch (Throwable e1) {
                try {
                    if (adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA2).toUpperCase().indexOf(SOFT_WORD) > -1) {
                        return PLATFORM_MOTOROLA;
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e2) {
                }
            }
        }
        // detecting SIEMENS
        try {
            Class.forName("com.siemens.mp.io.File");
            return PLATFORM_SIEMENS;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
        }
        // detecting LG
        try {
            Class.forName("mmpp.media.MediaPlayer");
            return PLATFORM_LG;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            try {
                Class.forName("mmpp.phone.Phone");
                return PLATFORM_LG;
            } catch (Throwable ex1) {
                try {
                    Class.forName("mmpp.lang.MathFP");
                    return PLATFORM_LG;
                } catch (Throwable ex2) {
                    try {
                        Class.forName("mmpp.media.BackLight");
                        return PLATFORM_LG;
                    } catch (Throwable ex3) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return PLATFORM_NOT_DEFINED;
    }

    /**
     * define real left soft key code by platform
     *
     * @return code
     */
    private int getLeftSoftkeyCode() {
        int keyCode = 0;
        try {
            if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_MOTOROLA)) {
                String softkeyLeftMoto = "";
                try {
                    softkeyLeftMoto = adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA).toUpperCase();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ilae) {
//                    ilae.printStackTrace();
                }
                String softkeyLeftMoto1 = "";
                try {
                    softkeyLeftMoto1 = adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA1).toUpperCase();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ilae) {
//                    ilae.printStackTrace();
                }
                String softkeyLeftMoto2 = "";
                try {
                    softkeyLeftMoto2 = adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA2).toUpperCase();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ilae) {
//                    ilae.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (softkeyLeftMoto.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0 && softkeyLeftMoto.indexOf("1") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA;
                } else if (softkeyLeftMoto1.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0 && softkeyLeftMoto1.indexOf("1") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA1;
                } else if (softkeyLeftMoto2.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0 && softkeyLeftMoto2.indexOf("1") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA2;
                } else if (softkeyLeftMoto.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0 && softkeyLeftMoto.indexOf("LEFT") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA;
                } else if (softkeyLeftMoto1.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0 && softkeyLeftMoto1.indexOf("LEFT") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA1;
                } else if (softkeyLeftMoto2.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0 && softkeyLeftMoto2.indexOf("LEFT") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA2;
                }

            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_NOKIA)) {
                return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_NOKIA;
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SAMSUNG)) {
//                String leftkeySamsungName = adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_LEFT_SAMSUNG).toUpperCase();
//                if (leftkeySamsungName.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0) {
//                    if (leftkeySamsungName.indexOf("1") >= 0) {
                return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_SAMSUNG;
//                    } else if (leftkeySamsungName.indexOf("LEFT") >= 0) {
//                        return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_SAMSUNG;
//                    }
//                }
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SIEMENS)) {
                String leftKeySiemensName = adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_LEFT_SIEMENS).toUpperCase();
                if (leftKeySiemensName.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0) {
                    if (leftKeySiemensName.indexOf("1") >= 0) {
                        return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_SIEMENS;
                    } else if (leftKeySiemensName.indexOf("LEFT") >= 0) {
                        return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_SIEMENS;
                    }
                }
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SONY_ERICSSON)) {
                return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_SE;
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_NOT_DEFINED)) {
                //
                for (int i = -125; i <= 125; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        i++;
                    }
//                    System.out.println(getKeyName(i).toUpperCase());
                    final String s = adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(i).toUpperCase();
                    if (s.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0) {
                        if (s.indexOf("1") >= 0) {
                            keyCode = i;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (s.indexOf("LEFT") >= 0) {
                            keyCode = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (keyCode == 0) {
                //#if emulator
                return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_NOKIA;
                //#endif
            }
        } catch (Throwable iaEx) {
            //#if emulator
            return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_NOKIA;
            //#endif
        }
        return keyCode;
    }

    /**
     * define real right soft key code for current platform
     *
     * @return code
     */
    private int getRightSoftkeyCode() {
        int keyCode = 0;
        try {
            if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_MOTOROLA)) {

                String rightSoftMoto1 = "";
                try {
                    rightSoftMoto1 = adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA1).toUpperCase();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ilae) {
//                    ilae.printStackTrace();
                }
                String rightSoftMoto = "";
                try {
                    rightSoftMoto = adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_MOTOROLA).toUpperCase();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ilae) {
//                    ilae.printStackTrace();
                }
                String rightSoftMoto2 = "";
                try {
                    rightSoftMoto2 = adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_MOTOROLA1).toUpperCase();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ilae) {
//                    ilae.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (rightSoftMoto.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0 && rightSoftMoto.indexOf("2") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_MOTOROLA;
                } else if (rightSoftMoto1.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0 && rightSoftMoto1.indexOf("2") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_MOTOROLA;
                } else if (rightSoftMoto2.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0 && rightSoftMoto2.indexOf("2") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_MOTOROLA1;
                } else if (rightSoftMoto.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0 && rightSoftMoto.indexOf("RIGHT") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_LEFT_MOTOROLA;
                } else if (rightSoftMoto1.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0 && rightSoftMoto1.indexOf("RIGHT") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_MOTOROLA1;
                } else if (rightSoftMoto2.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0 && rightSoftMoto2.indexOf("RIGHT") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_MOTOROLA;
                }

            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_NOKIA)) {
                return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_NOKIA;
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SAMSUNG)) {
//                String rightSoftSamsung = adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_SAMSUNG).toUpperCase();
//                if (rightSoftSamsung.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0) {
//                    if (rightSoftSamsung.indexOf("2") >= 0) {
                return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_SAMSUNG;
//                    } else if (rightSoftSamsung.indexOf("RIGHT") >= 0) {
//                        return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_SAMSUNG;
//                    }
//                }
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SIEMENS)) {
                String rightSoftSiemens = adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_SIEMENS).toUpperCase();
                if (rightSoftSiemens.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0) {
                    if (rightSoftSiemens.indexOf("4") >= 0) {
                        return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_SIEMENS;
                    } else if (rightSoftSiemens.indexOf("RIGHT") >= 0) {
                        return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_SIEMENS;
                    }
                }
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SONY_ERICSSON)) {
                return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_SE;
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_NOT_DEFINED)) {
                for (int i = -125; i <= 125; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        i++;
                    }
                    String keyName = adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(i).toUpperCase();
                    if (keyName.indexOf(SOFT_WORD) >= 0) {
                        if (keyName.indexOf("2") >= 0) {
                            keyCode = i;
                            break;
                        } else if (keyName.indexOf("4") >= 0) {
                            keyCode = i;
                            break;
                        } else if (keyName.indexOf("RIGHT") >= 0) {
                            keyCode = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable iaEx) {
            //#if emulator
            return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT_NOKIA;
            //#endif
        }
        return keyCode;
    }

    /**
     * define real middle soft key code for current platform
     *
     * @return code
     */
    private int getMidleORInternetSoftkeyCode() {
        try {
            if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_MOTOROLA)) {
                if (adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_MIDLE_MOTOROLA).toUpperCase().indexOf("SOFT") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_MIDLE_MOTOROLA;
                }
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_NOKIA)) {
                if (adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(SOFT_KEY_MIDLE_NOKIA).toUpperCase().indexOf("SOFT") >= 0) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_MIDLE_NOKIA;
                }
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SAMSUNG)) {
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SIEMENS)) {
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SONY_ERICSSON)) {
                return INTERNET_KEY_SE;
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * define real key's C or DELETE code for current platform
     *
     * @return code
     */
    private int getDeleteKeyCode() {
        try {
            if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_MOTOROLA)) {

            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_NOKIA)) {
                if (adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(DELETE_KEY_SE).toUpperCase().indexOf("CLEAR") >= 0) {
                    return DELETE_KEY_NOKIA;
                } else {
                    return DELETE_KEY_NOKIA;
                }
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SAMSUNG)) {
                if (adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(DELETE_KEY_SAMSUNG).toUpperCase().indexOf("CLEAR") >= 0) {
                    return DELETE_KEY_SAMSUNG;
                }
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SIEMENS)) {
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SONY_ERICSSON)) {
                if (adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(DELETE_KEY_SE).toUpperCase().indexOf("CLEAR") >= 0) {
                    return DELETE_KEY_SE;
                } else if (adaptorCanvas.getKeyName(DELETE_KEY_SE).toUpperCase().indexOf("C") >= 0) {
                    return DELETE_KEY_SE;
                } else {
                    return DELETE_KEY_SE;
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            return DELETE_KEY_SE;
        }
        return 0;
    }


    /**
     * define real key's BACK code for current platform
     *
     * @return code
     */
    private int getBackKeyCode() {
        try {
            if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_MOTOROLA)) {

            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_NOKIA)) {

            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SAMSUNG)) {
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SIEMENS)) {
            } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals(PLATFORM_SONY_ERICSSON)) {
                return BACK_KEY_SE;
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * name of curent platform
     *
     * @return PLATFORM_NAME
     */
    public String getPlatformName() {
        return PLATFORM_NAME;
    }

    /**
     * Used to adopt key kode to predefined constances, which are platform independent.
     * <p/>
     * You can use this method in any kind of canvas, but better at first time to call
     * <code>getInstance()</code> method at the beginning of midlet work, because initialisation takes time.
     * <p/>
     * Best variant for usage is calling <code>adoptKeyCode()</code> to use <code>keyPressed()</code> method in Canvas:
     * <pre>
     * protected void keyPressed(int keyCode) {
     *     keyCode = KeyCodeAdapter.getInstance().adoptKeyCode(keyCode);
     * }
     * </pre>
     * and then you can use it:
     * <pre>
     * switch (keyCode) {
     *   case KeyCodeAdapter.UP_KEY:
     *     break;
     *   case KeyCodeAdapter.SOFT_KEY_LEFT:
     *     break;
     * }</pre>
     * or send this code to any other clesses.
     *
     * @param keycode This code is sent by platform to canvas and redirected here
     * @return this keycode is equal to one of our constants declared in this class
     */
    public int adoptKeyCode(int keycode) {
        switch (keycode) {
            case Canvas.KEY_NUM0:
                return KEY_0;
            case Canvas.KEY_NUM1:
                return KEY_1;
            case Canvas.KEY_NUM2:
                return KEY_2;
            case Canvas.KEY_NUM3:
                return KEY_3;
            case Canvas.KEY_NUM4:
                return KEY_4;
            case Canvas.KEY_NUM5:
                return KEY_5;
            case Canvas.KEY_NUM6:
                return KEY_6;
            case Canvas.KEY_NUM7:
                return KEY_7;
            case Canvas.KEY_NUM8:
                return KEY_8;
            case Canvas.KEY_NUM9:
                return KEY_9;
            case Canvas.KEY_STAR:
                return KEY__STAR;
            case Canvas.KEY_POUND:
                return KEY__POUND;
            default:
                if (keycode == SOFTKEY_LEFT) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_LEFT;
                } else if (keycode == SOFTKEY_RIGHT) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_RIGHT;
                } else if (keycode == SOFTKEY_DELETE) {
                    return DELETE_KEY;
                } else if (keycode == SOFTKEY_BACK) {
                    return BACK_KEY;
                } else if (keycode == SOFTKEY_MIDDLE_INTERNET) {
                    return SOFT_KEY_MIDDLE_INTERNET;
                } else if (keycode == PENCIL_KEY_NOKIA) {
                    return PENCIL_KEY;
                } else {
                    try {
                        final int gameAction;
                        gameAction = adaptorCanvas.getGameAction(keycode);
                        if (gameAction == Canvas.UP) {
                            return UP_KEY;
                        } else if (gameAction == Canvas.DOWN) {
                            return DOWN_KEY;
                        } else if (gameAction == Canvas.LEFT) {
                            return LEFT_KEY;
                        } else if (gameAction == Canvas.RIGHT) {
                            return RIGHT_KEY;
                        } else if (gameAction == Canvas.FIRE) {
                            return CENTER_KEY;
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
//                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        //#if debug
        //# return keycode;
        //#else
        return NOT_DEFINED_KEY;
        //#endif
    }

    /**
     * return instance of class
     *
     * @return instance
     */
    public static KeyCodeAdapter getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

You have to use like this in your code:::-

```
protected void keyPressed(int keyCode) {  
        int internalKeyCode = KeyCodeAdapter.getInstance().adoptKeyCode(keyCode);  
        switch (keyCode) {  
            case KeyCodeAdapter.SOFT_KEY_LEFT:  
                // some processing  
                break;  
            case KeyCodeAdapter.BACK_KEY:  
                // some processing  
                break;  
            default:  
        }  
        ...  
    }
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur reply.I have already have this code.In this there nothing related to Micromax and BlackBerry mobiles.Can u please help in getting the keycode for Micromax and BlackBerry mobiles like above.

Comment: do one thing create simple canvas where it will print which key you pressed. Run this jar on micromax & check the key for left and right soft key. For blackbery i asked same question check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373998/how-to-use-soft-keys-in-blackberry-application